# Determining equivalent resistance to find the cutoff frequency

Tags: noise, voltage-reference, precision, filtering

I am designing a low noise circuit for a precision application and require a stable voltage supplied to the circuit. I have determined that the MAX6250 voltage reference best suits my circuit. A snippet of my schematic can be seen below:

[image: Circuit snippet]

I have added the output bypass capacitor to filter some high frequency noise and would like to know the theoretical cutoff frequency of the low pass filter created by C4. Am I correct in thinking that the equivalent resistance for the LPF is ~0.01Ohm, due to the output impedance of the MAX6250 at low frequencies? Or is the output impedance irrelavent and the resistance is (1k+R_in+500)||R_in, where R_in is the input resistance of the LT1007 (in the giga-ohm range).

Comment: The time constant (inverse of the 3dB-cut-off) of a first order RC block is always the product (C*Reff). And Reff is the effective resistance of the path for descharging the capacitor. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The impedance the capacitor sees is the output impedance of the MAX6250 in parallel with approximately R4 (because the virtual ground at U2 input is imperfect, especially at high frequencies) and U4 input. At low frequencies it’s clearly dominated by U1. From the below graph, also at high frequencies pretty much.

[image]

So clearly it will have effect mostly above 10kHz (impedance of the cap is about 7 ohms there). We don’t know the output impedance phase though. It’s possible the chip may be unstable at, say 20nF but not at 20pF and not at 2.2uF.

Comment: So, if a 50uF output bypass capacitor is used then the cutoff  frequency for 100kHz noise is 106Hz, but for 1000Hz noise it is 31.83kHz. How would I mathematically approximate the noise seen by other components?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this - there isn't enough information as the the nature of the output impedance. If you add some series resistance and buffer the output to prevent the loading of U2 (or draw the input for R4 from U4) then you can put the pole where you want.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I correct in thinking that the equivalent resistance for the LPF is
>   ~0.01Ohm, due to the output impedance of the MAX6250 at low
>   frequencies?

Nearly correct because, the output impedance will rise with frequency increases (see page 7 of the data sheet): -

[image]

So, if you had a noise problem at around 100 kHz the output impedance is 10 ohms rather than 0.02 ohms (10 Hz to 100 Hz). This might make you rethink the value of the capacitor and you might indeed pick a lower value AND that capacitor may perform better because, being lower in value, it will likely have a higher self-resonant frequency.